# invalid elf header linux

Tags: c++, gcc

I have ported a c++ code from an open solaris OS to Redhat 4 OS. In this code snippet iam am getting an error :

```
    AsciiFileName = new char [1024];
    cout<<"HandleFile is getting called "<<endl;
    /// Converting the file name to ascii.
    FileName += strFileName;
    FileName.ConvertToAscii( AsciiFileName );

    /// Get handle to the shared object file.
    Handle = dlopen( AsciiFileName, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY );
    cout<<"Handle = dlopen( AsciiFileName, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY ); is getting called AsciiFileName"<<AsciiFileName<<endl;
    if (!Handle)
    {
    cout<<"Handle is NULL"<<endl;
    cout<<dlerror()<<endl;
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

The error i am getting is :

```
invalid elf header linux
```

It is not able to open the so file.Here is the relevant log for it

```
Before ProcessSharedObject->IterateOnDir
 GCVDirectoryIterator::IterateOnDir:file name :/bin/ls /trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Telstra/USM/dat/CnEModules/*.so
 GCVDirectoryIterator::IterateOnDir:file opened  :/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Telstra/USM/dat/CnEModules/libGCVCore.so

before GCVDirectoryIterator::AddFile
HandleFile is getting called
Handle = dlopen( AsciiFileName, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY ); is getting called AsciiFileName/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Telstra/USM/dat/CnEModules/libGCVCore.so
Handle is NULL
/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Telstra/USM/dat/CnEModules/libGCVCore.so: invalid ELF header
```

Comment: are you trying to open a solaris .so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Telstra/USM/dat/CnEModules/libGCVCore.so: current ar archive

That's a static library (archive), and should be `.a`, not `.so`. You cannot open it with `dlopen`.

Comment: This is correct.I saw that during compilation it is showing "
 ADD_LIBRARY for library GenericUSMModules is used with the SHARED option, but the target platform supports only STATIC libraries. Building
 it STATIC instead. This may lead to problems.
".Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied libGCVCore.so from a Solaris machine to a RedHat machine. Most likely the Solaris machine have a different architecture (Sparc?) than the RedHat one. You can have a confirmation by typing:

```
file libGCVCore.so
```

This command should print info about the target architecture of the library you are trying to link.

Comment: No, all the required libraries are created here during compile time.those are not copied.

Comment: this command shows:/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Telstra/USM/dat/CnEModules/libGCVCore.so: current ar archive

Comment: That's a bit weird, the output should actually state that the file is a shared object, dynamically linked, and the target architecture (ex: x86-64)